# refresh a page in extjs

Tags: extjs

How can i refresh grid data when new data added in exts?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you add the new data, if it happens on the server and you want to refresh an Ext JS view:

```
grid.getStore().reload()
```

Answer (score 1):

i also fix it by

store.reload();

Answer (score 1):

reload is depreciated in js ext 4.  use load() for js ext 4.

Comment: See also the Sencha blog post about migrating from Ext JS 3.x to 4.x : http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-3-to-4-migration